# Cordova WP8 write JSON string to file

Tags: json, cordova, windows-phone-8, filewriter

For a Cordova WP8 app, how can I write a JSON string received as response from a web service to a local file?

I receive the JSON string as:

```
function saveFile() {
  $.post( testurl ,
         function (data) {
            // write to file here
         });
}
```

What is the simplest way to write the JSON string `data` to a file in a specific folder?